# ng2-smart-table, align text

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

How can we align text to right in *ng2-smart-table*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code, it works from my side.

```
this.settings.columns["title"] = { "title": this.settings.columns["title"].title, type:'html',valuePrepareFunction: function(value){
     return '<div class="customformat"> ' + value + ' </div>' 
}};
```

**CSS**

```
 :host /deep/ .customformat{ text-align: right; }
```

---

Comment: I used 
return '<div align="right"> ' + value + ' </div>' 

and it working, Thank you for the answer,

Answer (score 3):

There is another way by using the **css** only.

To move all columns to the right:

`:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table tbody > tr > td{
  text-align: right;
}`

To move all titles to the right:

`:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table thead th{
  text-align: center;
}`

To move all input filters to the right:

`:host /deep/ ng2-smart-table thead input-filter input{
    text-align: center;
}`

etc.

Comment: This one worked for me, I just had to use `:host ::ng-deep` instead of `:host /deep/`. Thanks.